# How can I add a variable to an array?

Tags: php, arrays

How can I add a variable to an array? Let say I have variable named `$new_values`:

```
$new_values=",543,432,888"
```

And now I would like to add `$new_values` to function. I tried in that way:

```
phpfunction1(array(114,763 .$new_values. ), $test);
```

but I got an error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ')'`

How my code should look if I would like to have `array(114,763,543,432,888)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$new_values=",543,432,888";
```

should be converted to an array:

```
$new_values= explode(',', "543,432,888");
```

and merged to existing values with:

```
array_merge(array(114,763), $new_values);
```

Whole code should looks like:

```
$new_values = explode(',', "543,432,888");
$values = array(114,763);
$values = array_merge($values, $new_values);
phpfunction1($values, $test);
```

If you pass to `explode` a string that is starting with `,` you will get first empty element, so avoid it.

Answer (score 5):

if you have an array already i.e.

```
$values = array(543,432,888);
```

You can add to them by : `$values[]=114; $values[]=763;`

Apologies if I missed the point there...

Comment: Thanks. This gave me idea to build my application in different way!

Answer (score 2):

In your example, $new_values is a string, but, since it's comma delimited, you can create an array directly from it. Use `$new_array = explode(',', $new_values);` to create an array from the string.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the string into an array using the explode function and then use the array_merge function to merge the two arrays into one:

```
$new_values=",543,432,888";

$currentArray=array(114,763);

$newArray=array_merge($currentArray,explode(',',$new_values));

functionX($newArray...)
```

But watch out for the empty array element because of the first comma.
For that use "trim($new_values, ',')" - see answer from rajesh.

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this.

```
$old_values = array(122,555);
$new_values=",543,432,888";
$values =  explode(',', trim($new_values, ','));
$result = array_merge($old_values, $values);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score -1):

[try array merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

looks like this

`phpfunction1(array_merge(array(114,763) ,$new_values), $test);`

and yes your first array is not an array
change it to this

`$new_values=Array(543,432,888);`

Comment: Nobody owes you an explanation for a down-vote. They're anonymous by design and you are in *no way* entitled to a comment.

Comment: @meagar ok here is the issue to be actually helpful to the OP and the COMMUNITY it is always a good idea to list the reasons WHY the question is worth a downvote.

Comment: Votes just let the best answers float upwards. This has been discussed ad nauseum and the community agrees, votes (up *or* down) should be anonymous and *not* require an explanatory comment. Chill out and stop taking down-votes as some kind of offensive gesture. They're not.